# What is the blendcache_learning folder?

Tags: system

Google gives me no results for this folder that appears in my project folder.

- Can I delete it?
- Can I disable it somehow?
- If it's not important why is it not kept in Blender's temporary folder somewhere?

Comment: There should be project called "learning" in the root of directory mentioned folder is in. In that project some baking was likely used, e.g. when baking simulation for fluid or smoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smoke simulations, and – if "*Disk Cache*" is selected – also cloth and soft body simulations, will create a folder called `blendcache_$file` where `$file` is the name of your `.blend` file (fluid simulations will create `cache_$file` instead).

Those folders contain the results of baking the physics. Deleting them clears the bake; to bring your bake around (to another computer) it's necessary to keep those folders as sub-folders of your project.